# Function does not finish and move on

Tags: python, function, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to trigger a function with Python and Selenium. Below is my code. I know it gets to the end because I've used the print function at the end and see the output. But once it's finished, my next function does not run and it does not throw an error, nor does it exit.

```py
def setupbrowser(self):
  chrome_options = Options()
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
  driver.get(url)
  driver.find_element(By.ID, loginfield).send_keys(username)
  self.snipe()
```

It does not run the next line `self.snipe()`.

Comment: What does `self.snipe()` do?

Comment: Is the function in same class ?

Comment: self.snipe() is another function in the code after the code does the send keys it does not do anything else after.

Comment: are you able to show us the implementation for ```snipe()```?

Comment: Hi snipe works when called on it own. the function in the question just never seems to finish or break out of it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How is `self.snipe()` defined?

Comment: What happens if you add `breakpoint` into `self.snipe()`?